# How can i use ffmpeg to extract audio from an video every 5 seconds

Tags: audio, ffmpeg

I need to extract audio from live stream. I want to generate an audio file every 5s.

- if i use the command
  `ffmpeg -i ***.flv -c:a aac -fs 128k output.aac`
  I can only get one file. but i want generate a file every 5s.
- if i use the commmand
  `ffmpeg -i ***.mp4 -vf fps=1/5.0 E:\image%d.jpg`
  I got an image every 1s.
  How can i do the same thing to extract audio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [segment muxer](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#segment_002c-stream_005fsegment_002c-ssegment):

```
ffmpeg -i input -map 0:a -f segment -segment_time 5 output_%03d.aac
```

Add `-c copy` and use a compatible output container format if you don't want to re-encode.